# How do I save terminal output from multiple commands to one file?

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I am running a command like this:

```
geocode 'New York, NY' --provider google; 
geocode 'Chicago, IL' --provider google;
geocode 'Portland, OR' --provider google
```

when I use `> geocode.txt` it only saves the result of the last command. 
How can I save the results of **all** commands in one text file?

Comment: Do not forget to mark answer as Solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

do something like this:

```
geocode 'New York, NY' --provider google > geocode.txt
geocode 'Chicago, IL' --provider google >> geocode.txt
geocode 'Portland, OR' --provider google >> geocode.txt
```

the >> command appends the stdout to the existing txt file